# Conda Installation Fails for PySoundFIle

Tags: python, anaconda, soundfile

I'm trying to understand why my conda installation of `pysoundfile` via the following command fails

```
conda install -n condaenv -c conda-forge  pysoundfile
```

The error message seems to complain about a missing comparability between the required python version and my installed version. But as far as I understand, the version I have in my conda environment is listed and should be supported, right? This is the error message:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: \
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.|
Examining python=3.7: 100%|█████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 3/3 [00:00<00:00, 16.26it/s]\failed

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found
to be incompatible with the existing python installation in your environment:

Specifications:

  - pysoundfile=0.10.2 -> python[version='2.7.*|3.5.*|3.6.*|3.6.9|>=2.7,<2.8.0a0|>=3.8,<3.9.0a0|>=3.7,<3.8.0a0|>=3.6,<3.7.0a0|>=3.5,<3.6.0a0|3.4.*',build=0_73_pypy]

Your python: python=3.7

If python is on the left-most side of the chain, that's the version you've asked for.
When python appears to the right, that indicates that the thing on the left is somehow
not available for the python version you are constrained to. Note that conda will not
change your python version to a different minor version unless you explicitly specify
that.

The following specifications were found to be incompatible with your CUDA driver:

  - feature:/win-64::__cuda==11.0=0

Your installed CUDA driver is: 11.0
```

I assume the warning about my cuda driver is a secondary issue that doesn't have anything to do with the `pysoundfile` installation. Does sombody know what's going on here and how I might bypass the issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to replicate this error with conda and python 3.7.

pip install pysoundfile works just fine if you want to install soundfile.

Comment: I did this as a work around but it's still a bit frustrating.